# Set rect focus in camera android

Tags: java, android, camera

I am doing an Android application that uses camera. I want that camera focuses in faces. My dude is: Nexus 5 front camera only has "Fixed" in focus mode. Is there some way to use setRect areas or something like that.

I try to use facedetectionlistener and runs ok but when i also add a previewcallback to do some process stops running. ([Issue with preview callback [ANDROID]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455622/issue-with-preview-callback-android))

Thanks

Comment: Please be much more specific as to what you're asking, what you've tried, and why what you've tried doesn't work.

Comment: I try to focus my camera to face location, but if i use facedetection listener and previewCallback together not runs facedetectionlisterner

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Camera.Parameters. It has setFocusArea and setAutoFocus functions.

Check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647/android-setfocusarea-and-auto-focus)